# Removing backslashes from values in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, escaping

I have a Pandas dataframe that contains backslashes. I want to strip out those backslashes, but I can't get the replace function to work. Here's what I'm doing:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data={'col1':['a\\b','ab'], 'col2':['c','cd\\']})
df.replace(to_replace='\\', value='', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

When I run this, I get an error message that says:

```
error: bad escape (end of pattern) at position 0
```

If I remove "regex=True", I don't get the error, but nothing get's replaced.

How do I remove the backslashes?

Comment: Use `df.replace(r'\\','', regex=True)` or `df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('\\',''))`

Comment: So, the example on the left is the same code I implemented except I specified the parameter names rather than just relying on their location, so I'll give it a try, but I anticipate the same error. The lambda expression may work for me (I'll certainly give it a try), but it I think this may be a bug in the implementation of the replace function. It seems as though the problem I'm having is a difference between what the Python compiler can accept as valid code and what the replace function can process as valid values once they're passed in.

Comment: Yup. "df.replace(r'\\','', regex=True)" and "df.replace(to_replace='\\', value='', regex=True)" produce exactly the same error.

Comment: I tried the lambda, and that gave me the desired result when I ran it against my sample dataframe from my original code snippet. However, actual data set has non-string columns in it, and that caused the following error:

    AttributeError: ('Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas', 'occurred at index RESTRICTED')

Comment: You can then select only the required columns and apply the function. If possible update the question with some actual sample data.

Comment: Sorry, I can't post actual data here as it is subject to GDPR rules. Adding an int column to my original dummy dataframe makes it more like the real thing though:

    df=pd.DataFrame(data={'col1':['a\\b','ab'], 'col2':['c','cd\\'], 'col3':[0,1]})
    df.replace(to_replace='\\', value='', regex=True, inplace=True)

Comment: `df.replace(to_replace= r'\\', value= '', regex=True)` This code works just fine for me on the sample data even with int column.

Comment: So all it needed was the r in front of the string to convert it to a raw string literal? Wow. Thank you, Abhi! If you put this as an answer rather than a comment I can mark it as my preferred answer. That way you'll get the credit for it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

```
df = df.replace(to_replace= r'\\', value= '', regex=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, Abhi. With the string literal flag (the "r" in front of '\\'), this works perfectly!

Comment: @ASturt Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the string API for each column.

```
for col in df:
    df[col] = df[col].str.replace(r'\\','')
```

Comment: Thanks James, but that on its own is not a great solution as I have multiple columns I need to remove backslashes from. Actually, if you look at the response from Abhi (who replied ahead of you), you'll see that he already suggested the string API but placed it in a lambda function so it better meets the criteria of the problem described in my original question. That said, his solution doesn't work against my actual data set as I have non-string columns in that. So, I may simply have to use your solution and deal with each column individually.